# guid REST URL for ado.net dataservice call?

Tags: rest, wcf-data-services

Trying to use a guid as a resource id in a rest url but cant find any resource on how to.
My best right now (not working though) is:
http://localhost:49157/PhotogalleryDS.svc/gallery('1d03beb3-6d63-498b-aad7-fab0b1480996')
(I've tried duouble/single quotes. And also {guid....} with braces. Still no luck.

i only get:


Syntax error '"' at position 0.

Question is: How would I (with regard to specification) write the url for a resource where the id is a guid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

http://localhost:49157/PhotogalleryDS.svc/photo(guid'01231cc7-1e26-4f33-9fdf-fdf7015267dd')

This is the way

Answer (score 0):

My best guess based on what you've written is that you're wrapping that URL in double quotes.  The position 0 in that error message probably refers to the character directly before http